# Summing cells from table

Tags: java, arrays

I seem to not be able to solve this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`

I understand the error, but the table is 5x5 and I think I have everything right for printing it.

```
public static int tulosta_matriisi(int[][] matriisi) {
    int i=0, j=0;
    for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            if(j == 4 && i <= 4)
                System.out.println(matriisi[i][j]);
            else if(i <= 4 && j <= 4)
                System.out.print(matriisi[i][j] +"\t");
        }
    }
    return matriisi[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Side note: I recommend using `{}` even if you only have one line of code. Once you add a line later on, you might run into trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid all this problem you have to use :

```
for(i = 0; i < matriisi.length; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j < matriisi[i].length; j++) {
...
```

When you get out your loop, the i and j will be incremented so you should not return `matriisi[i][j]` this make this error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`, so instead you should to return `matriisi[i-1][j-1]` so in the end your program should look like this :

```
public static int tulosta_matriisi(int[][] matriisi) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < matriisi.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matriisi[i].length; j++) {
            if (j == matriisi[i].length - 1 && i <= matriisi.length) {
                System.out.println(matriisi[i][j]);
            } else if (i <= matriisi.length && j <= matriisi[i].length) {
                System.out.print(matriisi[i][j] + "\t");
            }
        }
    }
    return matriisi[i - 1][j - 1];
}
```

Good luck

Comment: You're missing a `g` there.

Comment: yes I had the return wrong, I had no idea about that happening. thank you very much.